# Places for canyoning in England / Wales

Tags: uk, canyoning

I've always liked the idea of canyoning, but it seems that there's few places where it can be done in England. Does anyone know of any such places?

Comment: What is canyoning?

Comment: @studiohack The Wikipedia article is relatively good for this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canyoning

Comment: sounds right up my alley! I do this from time to time, didn't know there was a name for it! :P

Comment: @studiohack I've never done it (hence the question) but it sounds like something I'd really enjoy; hoping that it turns out it's possible!

Comment: Trust me - its absolutely brilliant fun... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually went Gorge Walking weekend before last near a place called Clydach (Cwm Dyar), and it was brilliant :) I went with a group of about fifteen of us and I organised it through a chap called Michael at http://www.lifechangingactivities.com/

There are some great places as @Berry120 has said in the Brecon Beacons such as the Afon Mellte - beautiful waterfalls. Often see groups down there. I went on my stag do near there last year and went swimming! But saw a few others clambering around in the river with ropes - tell tale sign!

In North Wales (Snowdonia National Park) sometimes see people near some of the valleys near Coed Y Brenin Forest Park.

Try also visting this site: http://www.canyonguides.org/ if you want to find places in Scotland

Lake District also has a few places for example the Esk Gorge.

Take my word for it, its absolutely great fun and can definitely recommend the above..

Answer (score 6):

[Canyoning](http://blueocean-adventure.co.uk/gorge-scrambling/) aka Gorge Walking or Gorge Scrambling takes place in the Brecon Beacons National Park, the best known location for this activity in the UK!

http://blueocean-adventure.co.uk/gorge-scrambling/

Comment: Note: I checked on May 22, 2018 and both these links are down.

Answer (score 5):

From a search around, it seems there's a number of places that do it in the SW of England, Devon seeming to come up a lot: http://www.yumping.co.uk/canyoning/south-west-england

The other place where it seems to be popular is in the Brecon Beacons in Wales, and around that general area: http://www.adventurebritain.com/canyoning-in-wales-uk/

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure**: I founded Big Blue Adventures

There's some epic canyoning activities or day tours / weekends for groups based around [canyoning in Wales](https://www.explorebigblue.com/canyoning-wales/) with [Big Blue Adventures](https://www.explorebigblue.com/). Gorge walking is the technical canyoning in south Wales with the Afon Mellte being the best option. North Wales in Snowdonia uses rope work for more traditional canyoning. New course being added for 2021 in the north!

Comment: Are you involved with the company you link to? And if not, can you explain how well you know them and how much experience with them you have?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting @Willeke. Daniel, we have a fairly strong policy against self-promotion. Please ensure you make your affiliations obvious to the reader.