# Good canyon (or canyoning) websites

Tags: canyoning

I was wondering if you guys knew about some good websites to find canyons on with the necessary information ? Necessary information being:

- Longest abseil
- French level (V.A.I.)
- Wether the canyon is open/closed
- The entrance of the canyon and the exit of the canyon
- The sensitivity to weatherconditions
- ...

A fine example is given by [the French canyonsite](http://www.descente-canyon.com/). There you can search the name of your canyon at the right of the site. For example if I look at the canyon "Barranco del Furco" (in Spain) i find the following [technical sheet](http://www.descente-canyon.com/canyoning/canyon/21051). It gives the necessary information (mentioned above) together with some pictures of the canyons and the state of the water in the canyon. This site mainly deals with French canyons but it also knows a lot of other canyons. Once you have enough reputation on this site, you are free to add other canyons.

Now I've also discovered an [English canyonsite](http://www.canyonguides.org/). They put the different canyons they know on a [Canyon Locations Map](http://www.canyonguides.org/guide-book/canyon-locations-map/). This site is very handy to find places which have canyons. However the data about canyons outside of England is rather limited. And the data about the canyons that they do know is not that extensive.

> The thing that I was wondering is the following:
>
> **Are there more websites like the two above?**
>
> The answer will probably be yes, so my follow-up question would be:
>
> **What are the addresses of these websites? How much information do they give? What region do they cover?**
>
> And maybe a followup:
>
> **Any tips to find these kind of websites ?**

Comment: Related [Places for canyoning in England / Wales](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/places-for-canyoning-in-england-wales)

Comment: Sorry I misread it. You want websites, yes? Not sites as in locations?

Comment: @Liam, websites yes ! :)

Comment: For the San Gabriel Mountains near Los Angeles: http://www.dankat.com/advents/advents.htm

Answer (score 4):

I often use ropewiki.  I'm not sure what they have listed globally, but they have really great write ups on lots of canyons in the US.  Includes detailed information on the approaches (length, elevation, sometimes landmarks, different approaches/extensions), the rappels (how many and how long), and even the weather conditions year round to suggest things like when a wetsuit might be a good idea.

http://ropewiki.com/Main_Page

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll keep this in mind when I'll ever come canyoning in America. I'm mostly interested in the Europe region (since that is where I live).